# C# regular expression (replace)

Tags: c#, regex

Assume I have the string:

> 10,11,12,13,14,ABC,DEF,GHI,66

I am looking to run a regex against it to only return 0-9 and the "," characters, essentially stripping anything else out.

I have looked at Regex.Replace, but something isn't quite right with it. My code below:

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"[0-9,]+");
string input = reg.Replace(input, delegate(Match m)
                {
                    return String.Empty;
                });
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: "something isnt quite right with it" - like what?

Comment: I'd also suggest `string input = reg.Replace(input, "");` (or `String.Empty` if you like it better). It is very curious you've found the callback variation before a simple string replace...

Comment: You have shown an assumed the string to start, but could you show what you want the result to be? for example: do you want it to be `10,11,12,13,14,66` so removing `ABC,DEF,GHI,`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do you just want a `^` in that?

```
input = Regex.Replace(input, @"[^0-9,]+", "");
```

Comment: Perhaps he want to delete the commas of the deleted substrings... AB,CD,12,EF,GH => 12, (or perhaps even 12)

Comment: @xanatos - so make it something like `@"([^0-9,]+,)"` instead. Oh, gotta love regular expression syntax.

Comment: @xanatos - that goes into the *wild speculation* category, but you can trim excess commas on the next step.

Comment: @Michael - digits and letters might be mixed, according to the current code: `a12v3,7y8z` -> `123,78`. If it isn't, it is much simpler - you can dimple match for all `[0-9]+`. Also, your regex requires a comma, it will not work on the last word (though that one is simple).

Comment: Thanks that did the trick - I previously also tried ^[0-9,]. Many thanks

Comment: @Kobi - I did say "something like". :) Regular expressions are incredibly powerful and very easy to write such that they are basically incomprehensible, but SO comments don't really lend themselves to such beasts...

Answer (score 1):

Would a match collection give you more control?

Using `\d+[^,]` you can get a collection of digits?

You could then loop through your collection and recreate your desired string.

using linq you could do the following:

```
var input = "10,11,12,13,14,ABC,DEF,GHI,66";
Regex re = new Regex(@"\d+[^,]");
input = (from Match m in re.Matches(input) select m.Value).Aggregate("", (acc, item) => acc + "," + item).TrimStart(',');
```

Comment: you could replace `\d+` with `[A-Za-z]+` if you just wanted the letters.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you may do it without regular expressions via analysis of what is required for your characters in set `[0123456789,]`.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
var testString = "10,11,12,13,14,ABC,DEF,GHI,66";
var split = testString.Split(',');
var result = String.Join(",", split.Where(element => element.All(c => Char.IsDigit(c))).ToArray());
```